# How to get XML markup in single node

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to write a tool in C# which will take any XML file (of undefined structure) and will generate a list of the names and values. I have this mostly working, except for instances where the XML contains a description node which has markup within it.  Take the following XML example:

```
<TESTROOT>
  <MAIN>
    <TITLE>This is a test title</TITLE>
    <VERSION>v1.0</VERSION>
  </MAIN>
  <CONTACT>
    <NAME>Some contact person</NAME>
    <ADDRESS>
      <LINE1>Address line 1</LINE1>
      <LINE2>Address line 2</LINE2>
      <TOWN>Some town here</TOWN>
      <POSTCODE>AN1 WH3</POSTCODE>
    </ADDRESS>
  </CONTACT>
  <DETAIL>
    <NOTES>
      <P>Some text may appear like this in markup tags.</P>
      <P>But is all contained within the NOTES node.</P>
      <P>These may appear in different places, not necessarily called NOTES.</P>
      <P>And may contain <a href="#">Some hyperlinks</a></P>
    </NOTES>
  </DETAIL>
</TESTROOT>
```

I'm using the following code to step through the above XML and get the node path and value:

```
public void RunMe()
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(testxmlstring);

    // Get root node
    XmlNode root = doc.SelectSingleNode("//TESTROOT");

    // Get node info recursive
    GetNode(root, "");
}

public void GetNode(XmlNode parent, string path)
{
    foreach(XmlNode n in parent.ChildNodes)
    {
        if (n != null)
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} = {1}", path, n.Value));

        if (parent.HasChildNodes)
            GetNode(n, path + @"\" + n.Name);
    }
}
```

With that sample XML and the code above, I get the following output:

```
\MAIN\TITLE = This is a test title
\MAIN\VERSION = v1.0
\CONTACT\NAME = Some contact person
\CONTACT\ADDRESS\LINE1 = Address line 1
\CONTACT\ADDRESS\LINE2 = Address line 2
\CONTACT\ADDRESS\TOWN = Some town here
\CONTACT\ADDRESS\POSTCODE = AN1 WH3
\DETAIL\NOTES\P = Some text may appear like this in markup tags.
\DETAIL\NOTES\P = But is all contained within the NOTES node.
\DETAIL\NOTES\P = These may appear in different places, not necessarily called NOTES.
\DETAIL\NOTES\P =     And may contain 
\DETAIL\NOTES\P\a = Some hyperlinks
```

As you can see, the NOTES node is being split over many lines because of the P tag (or whatever HTML tag appears within it).  What I'd really like is this...

```
\MAIN\TITLE = This is a test title
\MAIN\VERSION = v1.0
\CONTACT\NAME = Some contact person
\CONTACT\ADDRESS\LINE1 = Address line 1
\CONTACT\ADDRESS\LINE2 = Address line 2
\CONTACT\ADDRESS\TOWN = Some town here
\CONTACT\ADDRESS\POSTCODE = AN1 WH3
\DETAIL\NOTES = <P>Some text may appear like this in markup tags.</P><P>But is all contained within the NOTES node.</P><P>These may appear in different places, not necessarily called NOTES.</P><P>And may contain <a href="#">Some hyperlinks</a></P>
```

So after that lengthy intro, my question is this - is there a way to get the output I've shown above.  Is it possible to check for markup and get all markup within a node as one value?

Thanks,
S

Comment: the system cannot differentiate between a HTML tag and XML tag

Comment: Have a list of what you consider unwanted element names (i.e. "HTML" tags) and whenever you encounter one of them, stop deeper analysis?

Comment: That's the approach I was going to use next, but wasn't sure if there was an easier way.  I understand that markup is markup, whether it's in an XML file or otherwise but don't know enough about XmlDocument (or XDocument) to know whether there was provisioning for cases like these or not.

Comment: How is your program supposed to understand what to fetch and what not?

Comment: If I knew the answer to that, I wouldn't be asking. This question is about whether anyone else has needed to do this / found a way to approach the issue.

Comment: Yes but you must know the rule, not me ahah, what do you want to exclude?

Comment: Well the rule would be to concatenate nodes where the content contains any HTML formatting tags.  I've mostly found a way to do this now but would prefer something a bit tidier.

Comment: Give a look at my answer ^^

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper("xml.xml");
        Console.WriteLine("TEST WITHOUT BLACKLIST:\n");
        xmlMapper.PrintMap();
        Console.WriteLine("\nTEST WITH BLACKLIST:\n");
        xmlMapper.PrintMap(new List<string>() { "P" });
    }
}

class XmlMapper
{
    public string FilePath { get; private set; }
    public XDocument XDocument { get; private set; }

    public XmlMapper(string filePath)
    {
        LoadXML(filePath);
    }

    public void LoadXML(string filePath)
    {
        this.FilePath = filePath;
        this.XDocument = XDocument.Load(FilePath);
    }

    public void PrintMap(List<string> blacklist = null)
    {
        PrintElements(XDocument.Elements().ToList(), "", blacklist);
    }

    private void PrintElements(List<XElement> elements, string path, List<string> blacklist = null)
    {
        foreach (XElement element in elements)
        {
            string elementPath = path + "\\" + element.Name;

            if (blacklist != null && blacklist.Contains(element.Name.LocalName) == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} = {1}", elementPath, element?.ToString()));
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} = {1}", elementPath, element?.Value));
            }

            if (element.HasElements)
            {
                PrintElements(element.Elements().ToList(), elementPath, blacklist);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
TEST WITHOUT BLACKLIST:

\TESTROOT = This is a test titlev1.0Some contact personAddress line 1Address line 2Some town hereAN1 WH3Some text may appear like this in markup tags.But is all contained within the NOTES node.These may appear in different places, not necessarily called NOTES.And may contain Some hyperlinks
\TESTROOT\MAIN = This is a test titlev1.0
\TESTROOT\MAIN\TITLE = This is a test title
\TESTROOT\MAIN\VERSION = v1.0
\TESTROOT\CONTACT = Some contact personAddress line 1Address line 2Some town hereAN1 WH3
\TESTROOT\CONTACT\NAME = Some contact person
\TESTROOT\CONTACT\ADDRESS = Address line 1Address line 2Some town hereAN1 WH3
\TESTROOT\CONTACT\ADDRESS\LINE1 = Address line 1
\TESTROOT\CONTACT\ADDRESS\LINE2 = Address line 2
\TESTROOT\CONTACT\ADDRESS\TOWN = Some town here
\TESTROOT\CONTACT\ADDRESS\POSTCODE = AN1 WH3
\TESTROOT\DETAIL = Some text may appear like this in markup tags.But is all contained within the NOTES node.These may appear in different places, not necessarily called NOTES.And may contain Some hyperlinks
\TESTROOT\DETAIL\NOTES = Some text may appear like this in markup tags.But is all contained within the NOTES node.These may appear in different places, not necessarily called NOTES.And may contain Some hyperlinks
\TESTROOT\DETAIL\NOTES\P = Some text may appear like this in markup tags.
\TESTROOT\DETAIL\NOTES\P = But is all contained within the NOTES node.
\TESTROOT\DETAIL\NOTES\P = These may appear in different places, not necessarily called NOTES.
\TESTROOT\DETAIL\NOTES\P = And may contain Some hyperlinks
\TESTROOT\DETAIL\NOTES\P\a = Some hyperlinks

TEST WITH BLACKLIST:

\TESTROOT = This is a test titlev1.0Some contact personAddress line 1Address line 2Some town hereAN1 WH3Some text may appear like this in markup tags.But is all contained within the NOTES node.These may appear in different places, not necessarily called NOTES.And may contain Some hyperlinks
\TESTROOT\MAIN = This is a test titlev1.0
\TESTROOT\MAIN\TITLE = This is a test title
\TESTROOT\MAIN\VERSION = v1.0
\TESTROOT\CONTACT = Some contact personAddress line 1Address line 2Some town hereAN1 WH3
\TESTROOT\CONTACT\NAME = Some contact person
\TESTROOT\CONTACT\ADDRESS = Address line 1Address line 2Some town hereAN1 WH3
\TESTROOT\CONTACT\ADDRESS\LINE1 = Address line 1
\TESTROOT\CONTACT\ADDRESS\LINE2 = Address line 2
\TESTROOT\CONTACT\ADDRESS\TOWN = Some town here
\TESTROOT\CONTACT\ADDRESS\POSTCODE = AN1 WH3
\TESTROOT\DETAIL = Some text may appear like this in markup tags.But is all contained within the NOTES node.These may appear in different places, not necessarily called NOTES.And may contain Some hyperlinks
\TESTROOT\DETAIL\NOTES = Some text may appear like this in markup tags.But is all contained within the NOTES node.These may appear in different places, not necessarily called NOTES.And may contain Some hyperlinks
\TESTROOT\DETAIL\NOTES\P = <P>Some text may appear like this in markup tags.</P>
\TESTROOT\DETAIL\NOTES\P = <P>But is all contained within the NOTES node.</P>
\TESTROOT\DETAIL\NOTES\P = <P>These may appear in different places, not necessarily called NOTES.</P>
\TESTROOT\DETAIL\NOTES\P = <P>And may contain <a href="#">Some hyperlinks</a></P>
```